# Using same autogenerated ID

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables with a one to one relationship.

```
CONTACT
  id (auto generated)
  ...


CONTACT_ADDRESS
  id
  ...
```

with Java I have the two classes populated. Contact gets an ID autogenerated. Is there a way to put the same ID in CONTACT_ADDRESS.id while saving it all at once?

If there isn't one, I will save CONTACT, retrieve that ID and put it into CONTACT_ADDRESS.id.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived

Comment: @JBNizet thanks a lot! Feel free to write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

You must use composition.

```
class Contact {

private long id (auto generated);
@OneToOne
private Contact_Adress contact;// Reference to the other object/table

}

class Contact_Adress {
  private long id(auto generated);

 // the object data here


}
```